# Definition style preferences

Tags: f#

What is the preferable style for F# definitions?

The [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534952119) I am studying makes regular use the following style:

```
let foo = fun x y -> 
    let aux1 = fun z -> z * 2 
        in aux1 x + 
    let aux2 = fun q -> q * 3 
        in aux2 y;;
```

On the other side, when I look for information on the web, it is most likely to meet something like:

```
let foo (x: int) (y: int) =
    let aux1 (z:int) = z * 2
        in aux1 x +
    let aux2 (q: int) = q * 3
        in aux2 y;;
```

On the [Guide](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/) I failed to find a reference about it. Is it a matter that goes beyond "*mere style*"? There are efficiency implications behind these two approaches?

What does your experience suggest?

Comment: That's a scheme book you are referencing. The second version is idiomatic to define F# functions, which I guess is supported by the fact that most code is written in that style. Also in is not used with #light style being the default in F# since for a long time.

Comment: It is our coursebook. I integrate with [Functional programming with F#](https://www.amazon.it/dp/1107684064/ref=asc_df_110768406446546158/?tag=googshopit-21&creative=23390&creativeASIN=1107684064&linkCode=df0&hvdev=c&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=). I like it.

Comment: U should accept the answer.

Comment: I will for sure. I am just doing some research and practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, F# function definitions tend to do one of two things:

1. Define as few types as possible (`let foo x y = ...`). This is the case for most functions. Or...
2. Explicitly define the types of each argument *and the return type* (`let foo (x : int) (y : int) : int = ...`.

Style #2 is rare, and I've usually seen it for functions that are explicitly part of the API of a module, and that have `///` comments to provide documentation as well. For internal functions, though, the typeless variant is usually used, since F#'s type inference works so well.

Also, as s952163 pointed out in a comment, the `in` keyword is almost never used anymore, since the `#light` style makes it unnecessary. I'd expect to see your sample code written as follows in modern F# style:

```
let foo x y =
    let aux1 z = z * 2
    let aux2 q = q * 3
    (aux1 x) + (aux2 y)
```

No `;;` necessary, either, unless you're typing into the F# Interactive console. If you're using VS Code + Ionide, and highlighting segments of code and pressing <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> to send them to F# Interactive, then you don't need any `;;` separators because Ionide adds them automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your information! It helped me to develop further research, that I tried to concentrate in the following answer. Do you think that I got it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I found evidence suggesting that the first style, even if today unconventional, is intrinsically connected to currying and anonymous functions.

Currying is a powerful characteristic of F#, where, I remember, every function could take *only one* parameter. For example:

```
let add x y = x + y 
val add: int -> int -> int
```

The signature is interpreted as ***add*** is a function that takes two integers as input and return an integer.
When compile time comes, the function is interpreted like:

```
let add2 = fun x -> fun y -> x + y
val add2: int -> int -> int
```

where `val add2: int -> int -> int` is semantically equivalent to `val add: (int -> (int -> int))`

By providing an argument to `add2`, such as `6`, it returns `fun y -> 6 + y`, which is another function waiting for its argument, while `x` is replaced by `6`.
Currying means that every argument actually returns a separate function: that's why when we call a function with only few of its parameters returns another function.

If I got it correctly, the more common F# syntax of the second example, `let add x y = x + y`, could be thought like syntactic sugar for the explicit currying style shown above.